# some question about expected value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a non negative random variable.
We Know that $E(X)=0$.

Is that correct that $X=0$ for some $X$.

And more general:

Is there a point in the probability space for which

E[X]≤X

and a point for which X≤E[X].

@Did: I Corrected it!

Thanks in advance

Comment: when you say $E[X]\leq X$ to mean that expected value is less than some value of the support of $X$

Comment: Is there a point in the probablity space for which $E[X] \leq X$ and a point for which $X \leq E(X)$?

Comment: "let X be a distribution" No, X is a random variable, not a distribution. "is it true that E[X]≤X for some X" What? For some X? What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a non-negative random variable, then it is not possible that $X \lt 0$.

If $X$ is a non-negative random variable and $E[X]=0$, then

- it is not possible that $X \lt E[X]$
- $\Pr(X=E[X])=\Pr(X=0)=1$
- $\Pr(X\le E[X])=\Pr(E[X] \le X)=1$
- $\Pr(X \gt E[X])=\Pr(X \gt 0)=0$

However it might be possible that $X \gt 0$, even if with zero probability.

For example, consider $Y$ as a random variable uniformly distributed on the real numbers in $[0,1]$ and let $X=0$ when $Y$ is irrational and $X=1$ when $Y$ is rational: then $X$ is a non-negative random variable, $E[X=0]$, $\Pr(X=0)=1$, and $\Pr(X=1)=0$, but it is possible for $X$ to be $1$, i.e. for $E[X]\lt X$.

Comment: And what about second part of question? $X$ is a random variable(not necessarily non-negative).Is there a point in the probability space for which
$E[X]≤X$
and a point for which $X≤E[X]$.